# Secure updates of chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have a chrome app that will be distributed as a normal file and not use the app store.  I would like a way of updating it, preferably using the auto-update facility.  However, I do not want to use an unsecured URL for the updates.

Is it possible to use any kind of authentication for updates?  What approaches could I use to secure updates that would not be accessible to unauthorized users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could customize each download of your app to have a different update URL. This could include credentials, or a token, that you gather during the conversion process leading to the initial download. In the event you find that a user has shared his unique URL, you could disable future updates from that URL, or update the app to a nonfunctional version.

As far as other approaches go, the update URL isn't parameterizable (other than [certain predefined parameters](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html)), so you can't customize it after installation. I am fairly sure that the request doesn't include the update origin's cookies. So an approach like signing in to the origin through a web page and setting a cookie there won't work.